# Approximating Lambert W-function as a fraction of logarithm

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, approximation, lambert-w

I need to solve an equation and I was able to find a solution in terms of Lambert W-function. However I need to solve the same equation for another set of parameters. I need to compare the root of those two equations but the relation is too complicated, The major complexity is posed because of Lambert W-function. Therefore I need to find a way to approximate $W(x)$ with logarithm.

I know the results that $W(x) \approx \ln x - \ln \ln x + \frac{\ln \ln x}{\ln x}+\cdots$ and also I know that

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{W(x)}{\ln x} = 1$$

However non of these are helpful.

I was wondering is there anyway I can find a relation like $W(x) \approx \alpha \ln x$ for a known $\alpha$ when $x$ is large but bounded?

I am interested in $x \in (10^3,10^4)$

Comment: Maybe useful see https://www.researchgate.net/publication/253513440_Inequalities_on_the_Lambert_W_function_and_hyperpower_function good luck !

Comment: @Erik Satie thank you for the comment, I've read that paper, there is so many bright ideas there, but all of them are about bounding $W(x)$ with $\ln x - \ln \ln x + \text{something extra}$ and there is not a bound like $\alpha \ln x$. Is this idea plausible at all?!

Comment: What is the range in which you want to approximate $W(x)$ this way ?

Comment: @Peter the range of $x$ in $W(x)$ is $(10^3,10^4)$.

Comment: Use $\alpha=0.777$

Comment: @K.K.McDonald A better approximation, in the sense of the norm given by Claude, for your interval is $$
W(x) \approx \ln x - \ln \ln x + \alpha \frac{{\ln \ln x}}{{\ln x}}
$$ with $\alpha = 0.996924749596985635453490\ldots$.

Comment: @Gary, thank you, this is a very good approximation, but unfortunately I can't use it in my problem, I was trying to get rid of that pesky $\ln \ln x$ term somehow and it worked with $\alpha \ln x$. I'm sure your nice suggestion will come in handy i future problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to get the approximation you look for, consider the norm
$$\Phi(\alpha)=\int_{10^3}^{10^4} (W(x)-\alpha  \log (x))^2\, dx$$

The definite integral is known. Now, differentiating $\Phi(\alpha)$ with respect to $\alpha$ we have a nasty linear equation; numerically, its solution is $\alpha=0.778164$.

The simplest would be a linear regression. Done, it leads to the same parameter and $R^2=0.999941$
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 \alpha & 0.778164 & 0.000063 & \{0.778040,0.778287\} \\
\end{array}$$

**Edit**

We can improve the approximation adding a linear term. So, now the norm
$$\Psi(\alpha,\beta)=\int_{10^3}^{10^4} (W(x)-\alpha  \log (x)-\beta)^2\, dx$$

All required antiderivatives are known. Differentiating with respect to $\alpha$ and $\beta$ leads to two linear equations from which
$$\alpha=0.864126\qquad \text{and} \qquad \beta=-0.731281$$

The improvement is interesting
$$\Phi_{\text{min}}=23.1588\quad \text{and} \quad \Psi_{\text{min}}=0.0740 \quad\implies\quad \frac{\Phi_{\text{min}} } {\Psi_{\text{min}} }=313$$

Comment: Thank you, I'll use this one!

Comment: WE could do better. Tell what are your limitations.

Comment: I think this is good enough, although I do not know what do you mean by limitations! I was going to use this approximation to compare solution of two set of optimization problems and the equations I referred to are K.K.T. conditions. Then I have to replace the solution in objective and compare but comparing two Lambert-W is not easy, specially when you have a huge sum of functions with Lambert-W argument! Now I have to check if something can be done with this approximation, or else I have to come back for some other idea!

Comment: @K.K.McDonald. For example, for this range, $W(x)=0.864124 \log(x)-0.731259$ is better. We could add the square of the logarithm ....

Comment: I got it now, but only the linear term is best, because I have terms of the form $\frac{W(x_1)-\alpha_1}{W(x_2)-\alpha_2}$ and using linear approximation make it much more easier, thank you!

Comment: Why is the equation in $\alpha$ nasty? I get that $\alpha =\frac{\int_a^b W(x)dx}{\int_a^b \ln x dx}$ and both integrals have closed form antiderivatives, did I do something wrong?

Comment: @Joe Aren't you missing an extra factor of $\ln x$ in the integrands coming from the cahin rule?

Comment: Oh yes my mistake

Comment: @Joe. No luke ! I was hoping a $100\pi$ improvement !